# How do I quickly hide a hierarchy of pages from search engines and external users?

Tags: pages, hierarchical

I use Multisite to manage the various languages of a web site.

The original language site has a huge page hierarchy (navigation items with plenty of sub-pages and sub-sub-pages), à la

[image]

I've cloned the original language version into a new language copy.

However, only a fraction of the content is currently translated to the new language, so there's several menu items I need to hide from the public. I only want to hide them, not delete them, so editors can continue translating the missing content behind the scenes.

I've naturally removed the menu entries corresponding with each page I want to hide, but I fear Google will manage to index the rest anyway, as it somehow usually does, leading to unsuspecting users being directed to incomplete, broken, un-translated content.

How can I hide an entire hierarchy of pages in Wordpress (e.g. "menu3" and all its children in the sketch above)?

- Setting the hierarchy's topmost page's status ("menu3") to "private" doesn't affect the status of the sub-pages and I would have to manually change the status for each sub-page
- Keeping Google from indexing the hidden content is an option, but it's work and it's easy to forget to remove once the content is translated
- Making the hierarchies inaccessible using `.htaccess` directives is also an option, but then editors will be unable to work on the pages - so not an option

Is there a way to do this in Wordpress? Ideally, without plugins, but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem is that you use multi-site for translations in the first place.

I strongly suggest [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) for translations as it's more reliable and doesn't require that much maintenance.

In your case I suggest you use [Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) or a SEO plugin that allows you to control the [indexing status](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) of your post/cpt or individually per post.
Basically, you just set the *meta robots* to *noindex*

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```